# how to create section and tabs in admin panel

Tags: admin

how to create new section an[image]d new tab in admin panel.
i have tried groups under sections and fields under groups, but not able to create sections.
Could you please explain in detail how to create sections and tabs in admin panel...

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Check the `system.xml` file inside `Mage/Wishlist/etc`. and try to build something similar

Comment: Relevant to your interests: http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration

Comment: Hope this will help.http://www.ecomdev.org/2010/10/27/custom-configuration-fields-in-magento.html

Comment: thanks for the help, all above links are helped me to resolve my problem, thanks once again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all the details please check the links provided by Alan Storm and others.
As this has been documented extensively before I will only provide a simple example for the sake of answering the question.

1. Create your own extension with your namespace (called `Vendor` in the following) and extension name (`Extensionname`).
2. Add the file `app/code/[codePool]/[Vendor]/[Extensionname]/etc/system.xml`. From your text I assume that you already did that.
3. First important bit: when adding a new section, specify the correct tab name as specified in the system.xml under

   ```
   <config>
     <tabs>
       <[tabname] translate="label" module="[module]">
         <label>Tab name</label>
         <sort_order>10</sort_order>
       </[tabname]>
     </tabs>
   </config>
   ```

   E.g.

   ```
   <config>
     <sections>
       <yoursection translate="label" module="customer">
         <class>separator-top</class>
         <label>Your section</label>
         <tab>customer</tab> <!-- the important one -->
         <sort_order>10</sort_order>
         <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
         <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
         <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
       </yoursection>
     </sections>
   </config>
   ```
4. Add your groups and fields as usual.
5. Second important bit add the section to the ACL in `app/code/[codePool]/[Vendor]/[Extensionname]/etc/adminhtml.xml` so that you can enter the section (after you have added the permission to the backend users and logged out/in again).

   ```
   <config>
       <acl>
           <resources>
               <admin>
                   <children>                 
                       <system>
                           <children>
                               <config>
                                   <children>
                                       <yoursection translate="title" module="customer">
                                           <title>Your section</title>
                                           <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                                       </yoursection>
                                   </children>
                               </config>
                           </children>
                       </system>
                   </children>
               </admin>
           </resources>
       </acl>
   </config>
   ```

Even without groups and fields you should be able to see the section.